# Search returns document after delete

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the weird effect that a search on an index returns a document I have just deleted before. A "get" works correctly. Am I doing something wrong? The search has no restrictions(`client.prepareSearch("test").execute(...)`)

I'm running an "ESIntegTestCase" with Elastic Search 5.0

```
@Test
public void testES() throws Exception {

    String index = "test";
    String type = "event";
    String doc = "{\"Key0\":\"Val0\"}";

    createIndex(index);

    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);

    client().prepareIndex(index, type).setSource(doc).execute(handleOrError(postResp -> {
        client().prepareGet(postResp.getIndex(), postResp.getType(), postResp.getId()).execute(handleOrError(getResp -> {
            printGR(getResp);
            client().prepareSearch(postResp.getIndex()).execute(handleOrError(searchResponse -> {
                printSR(searchResponse);
                client().prepareDelete(postResp.getIndex(), postResp.getType(), postResp.getId()).execute(handleOrError(resp -> {
                    printDR(resp);
                    client().prepareGet(postResp.getIndex(), postResp.getType(), postResp.getId()).execute(handleOrError(getResp2 -> {
                        printGR(getResp2);
                        client().prepareSearch(postResp.getIndex()).execute(handleOrError(searchResponse2 -> {
                            printSR(searchResponse2);
                            sem.release();
                        }));
                    }));
                }));
            }));
        }));
    }));

    sem.acquire();
}
```

Prints:

```
1) GetResponse: {"_index":"test","_type":"events","_id":"AVgv1NHPHZ0vJaA-eRhJ","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"Key0":"Val0"}}


2) SearchResponse:{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"events","_id":"AVgv1NHPHZ0vJaA-eRhJ","_score":1.0,"_source":{"Key0":"Val0"}}]}}


3) DeleteResponse: DeleteResponse[index=test,type=events,id=AVgv1NHPHZ0vJaA-eRhJ,version=2,result=deleted,shards="_shards"{"total":2,"successful":2,"failed":0}]


4) GetResponse: {"_index":"test","_type":"events","_id":"AVgv1NHPHZ0vJaA-eRhJ","found":false}


5) SearchResponse:{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"test","_type":"events","_id":"AVgv1NHPHZ0vJaA-eRhJ","_score":1.0,"_source":{"Key0":"Val0"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the difference between the search index and doing a get request. A get request also makes use of the transaction log. If you want the delete to have an effect on search, you need to execute a refresh. With elastic 5 there now is an option to wait for a refresh after an insert or a delete. Using that functionality should give you what you want. More information can be found here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html

Comment: Thank you! Changing the refresh policy for the delete fixed the problem.